# Flatten array into one object while reducing one property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object which contains arrays of worked dates of two employees, gruped by their id.

```
var employeeWorkedHours = {
  1: [
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 1, date: 7/1/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 2, date: 7/2/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 3, date: 7/3/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 4, date: 7/4/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 5, date: 7/5/2017}
],
2: [
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 5, date: 7/1/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 4, date: 7/2/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 3, date: 7/3/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 2, date: 7/4/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 1, date: 7/5/2017}
] }
```

I want to iterate over it, and merge each array into a single object:

```
Object.keys(employeeWorkedHours).map((emp) => { 
  emp.map((day) => {
    // expected output: one single object
    // { employeeId: X, totalHours: sum of hours of each line }
  })}
})}
```

Thanks

Comment: Expected output please...

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: Honestly, I think you'd be better off restructuring your data, then using `reduce` for a single output object or array.

Comment: @trincot The values are.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, I know. The question was edited after my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` for that:

```js
const employeeWorkedHours = {
  1: [
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 1, date: 7/1/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 2, date: 7/2/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 3, date: 7/3/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 4, date: 7/4/2017},
     { employeeId: 1, hours: 5, date: 7/5/2017}
],
2: [
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 5, date: 7/1/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 4, date: 7/2/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 3, date: 7/3/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 2, date: 7/4/2017},
   { employeeId: 2, hours: 1, date: 7/5/2017}
] };

const result = Object.keys(employeeWorkedHours).map((emp) => { 
  return employeeWorkedHours[emp].reduce((acc, day) => {
    acc.totalHours += day.hours;
    return acc;
  }, {employeeId: +emp, totalHours: 0} );  
});

console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation

`Object.keys(employeeWorkedHours)` will give the array of property names of the outer object, so `["1", "2"]`. In the `map` callback, `emp` will get each of these two values. So `employeeWorkedHours[emp]` is the array associated with that key.

Then `reduce` will build and return the desired object for that employee as follows: it starts with value `{employeeId: +emp, totalHours: 0}` (the second argument to `reduce`), which becomes the first argument of the callback, i.e. `acc`. The second argument of the callback takes the value of each inner object for that employee (e.g. `{ employeeId: 1, hours: 1, date: 7/1/2017}`). The hours of that entry are added to the object that is being accumulated (to `acc`). The mutated `acc` object is returned again to the `reduce` internals, which will pass it to the next call of the callback. And so the object is finalised and eventually returned by `reduce`.

The result of `reduce` is returned to the `map` internals, which in turn will return an array of results: one value (object) per employee.

#### Assumption

I assume the properties of the main object correspond to the `employeeId` of the inner objects. If this is not the case, then you would need to add:

```
acc.employeeId = day.employeeId;
```

Comment: why is this hard to understand? :(

Comment: @AravindhGopi, you get used to it after a while. Especially for you I added an explanation to my answer ;-)

Comment: Thats coooool. Thank you :)